# Different blanks between using an existing command and using its shorthand via \DeclareMathOperator

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I found using the existing command itself and using its shorthand via \DeclareMathOperator give differrent blanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\inc}{\hookrightarrow}
\DeclareMathOperator{\les}{\leqslant}
\begin{document}

\noindent
$A \inc B$\\
$A \hookrightarrow B$\\
$A \les B$\\
$A \leqslant B$

\end{document}
```

The result is in the picture:

[image]

**Question 1:**

> What's the reason behind this?

**Answer by *Steven B. Segletes* :**

> It is because these (original) things are `\mathrel`, rather than `\mathop` (which is what `\DeclareMathOperator` turns them into).

**Question 2:**

How to abbreviate the existing command(s)?

**Answer by *John Kormylo* :**

> Try `\let\inc=\hookrightarrow`.

Detailed answer by *egreg* is given below.

Comment: Have you tried `\let\inc=\hookrightarrow` ?

Comment: It is because these (original) things are `\mathrel`, rather than `\mathbin` (which is what `\DeclareMathOperator` turns them into).

Comment: With `\DeclareMathOperator` you define something that behaves like “sin” as pertains to spacing. If you want to abbreviate `\hookrightarrow` just do `\newcommand{\inc}{\hookrightarrow}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\mathop` rather than `\mathbin`

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the valued correction. "It is because these (original) things are `\mathrel`, rather than **`\mathop`** (which is what `\DeclareMathOperator` turns them into)"

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry, I didn't know this before. It works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\DeclareMathOperator` for new symbols that should behave similarly to “sin”, “log” and so on. Arrows or, in general, relation symbols obey completely different rules.

A simple alias for an existing command is better defined with `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\inc}{\hookrightarrow}
\newcommand{\les}{\leqslant}
```

A different approach is needed if you want to completely replace the standard `\leq` or `\geq` with the slanted variants:

```
\let\leq\leqslant \let\le\leq
\let\geq\geqslant \let\ge\geq
```

so the commands are effectively replaced. Just doing `\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant}` might suffice, but you would not be able to use `\le` as alias.